# I am writing C function that convert lowercase char to upper case char with using ASCII but Output is not correct

Tags: c, c-strings, uppercase, string-literals, function-definition

Okay, So I start working on this, I have code below;

+I also have strlen("any string here") func that return len of any str in decimal just keep in your mind.

I take a lover case let's say a, then a will be equal some decimal num in ASCII table then I subtract 32 to get A.

Sadly this is not working, any idea for this?
Thank you for all help and your time!

```
int uppercase(char sent[]) {
    
 for(int i=0; i <= strlen(sent); ++i) {
        if(sent[i]>='a' && sent[i]<='z')
            sent[i] -= 32;
}
```

Comment: For starters the function returns nothing though its return type is not void and it seems the condition in the for loop should be for(int i=0; i < strlen(sent); ++i)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) The "not working" doesn't  convey very much, can you please be more specific?

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?  Your example doesn't show anything but a for loop with a slight error with the `i <= strlen()` portion that won't actually change its functioning due to accidentally excluding the NUL character in your if statements.

Comment: If that is you own `strlen("any string here")` function please include that in the MVE.

Comment: @Bobamas Are you trying to convert a string literal?

Comment: I fixed for condition and tried again like this uppercase("Hello world"); But in console it give me segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @Bobamas You may not change a string literal. Declare an array like char s[] = "Hello world"; And call the function uppercase( s );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void uppercase(char sent[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)strlen(sent); i++) {
        if (sent[i] >= 'a' && sent[i] <= 'z') {
            sent[i] -= 32;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1){
        uppercase(argv[1]);
        puts(argv[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without any errors and warnings (using `clang`), even with options `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Thank you for this comment! It is so much helpfull!!!

Answer (score 1):

The function is declared as having the return type `int` but returns nothing.

```
int uppercase(char sent[]) {
    
 for(int i=0; i <= strlen(sent); ++i) {
        if(sent[i]>='a' && sent[i]<='z')
            sent[i] -= 32;

}
```

In general for a function that deals with strings the condition of the for loop should look at least like

```
 for(int i=0; i < strlen(sent); ++i) {
```

Though it is better to write the loop like

```
 for( size_t i = 0, n = strlen(sent); i < n; ++i ) {
```

However there is no great sense to use the function `strlen` in the function `uppercase`. Its call is redundant.

Pay attention to that you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Also it is better not to use the magic number `32`.

The function can be written the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * uppercase( char *s )
{
    for ( char *p = s; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( 'a' <= *p && *p <= 'z' ) *p = *p & ~' ';
    }
    
    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "hello world!";
    
    puts( s );
    puts( uppercase( s ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
hello world!
HELLO WORLD!
```

As for the function `strlen` then it is better to use another name for the function because it will conflict with the standard C function `strlen`.  And the function itself can be defined the following way

```
size_t string_len( const char *s )
{
    const char *p = s;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    return p - s;
}
```

Comment: Vlad thank you so much this is so smooth code, If you available can I ask you something also? So i need to use argc argv parameters in main function how can i edit it with that because i am coding with 3 different module file. Thank you so much again for this smooth code.

Comment: @Bobamas It is unclear for me how argc and argv are related to the function. You can close this question selecting the best answer and then ask a new question.

Comment: Btw Mr. Vlad what is that size_t in string_len() function ?

Comment: @Bobamas size_t is an unsigned integer type usually defined as an alias for the type unsigned long. It is the type used in the declaration of the standard string function strlen and the type of the value returned by the sizeof operator.

Comment: Another quick question how can I prototype this char * uppercase () and size_t string_len() functions in a header file?

Comment: @Bobamas Place their declarations in the header as for example char * uppercase( char *s ); and define them in some c module.

Comment: I got error like > conflicting types for 'uppercase'.

Comment: @Bobamas Try to copy and paste the code without typos. The header shall have header guards.

Comment: Mr Vlad I am still reading your code, pls understand my odd understanding because of being newbie but can you able to explain word by word that uppercase() function please ? Like how did you manage to handle without using strleng function like how did you construct for loop? thank you so much!

Comment: @Bobamas A string is a sequence of characters terminated by the zero character '\0'. If the current value of the pointer p points to the zero character then the expression *p is equivalent to *p != '\0'

Answer (score 1):

This code can help you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void uppercase(char T[],int k)
{
      int i=0;
      while(i<k)
      {
           if(T[i]>='a'&&T[i]<='z')
           {
                 T[i]=(char)((int)T[i]-32);
           }
         i++;
      }
      i=0;
      while(i<k)
      {
            printf("%c",T[i]);
            i++;
      }
      printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
      char T[]="good morning !";
      int k=sizeof(T);
      uppercase(T,k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
Parsing the string, then making the letters to uppercase.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>



int strlen(char s[]){ //String length function
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++);
    return i;
}

void uppercase(char sent[]) {
    for(int i=0; i < strlen(sent); ++i) {
        if(sent[i]>='a' && sent[i]<='z')
            sent[i] += 32;
    }

 printf("%s", sent);
}
```

this is a whole tab of my whole work. when i try uppercase("hello world"); it giving me core dumped console problem.

Comment: Remove the answer. You can update your question with this text.